# Estimating two integrals over the sphere

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Is there any easy way to estimate the following integrals over the uniform n-dimensional ball $B = \{\vec{x} : \left\|\vec{x}\right\|^2 \leq 1\}$?

$$
\begin{split}
f(c) &= \int_B e^{-cx_1} dx\\
g(c) &= \int_B \left( 1-\|x\|^2 \right)e^{-cx_1} dx
\end{split}
$$

where $x_1$ is the first coordinate of $\vec{x}$.

Comment: In 1D, you get $$f(c) = \int_{-1}^1 e^{-cx}dx = \frac{e^c-e^{-c}}{c}$$ and in 2D, depending on how yuo formulate the double integral you either get
$$
2\int_{-1}^1 e^{-cx} \sqrt{1-x^2} dx
 = \frac{1}{c}
    \int_{-1}^1 \left[ e^{c\sqrt{1-y^2}} - e^{-c\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right] dy
 = \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-cr\cos \theta} r dr d\theta
$$ and all are quite nasty

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to do is to change to spherical coordinates.  Then $x_1= \rho cos(\theta)sin(\phi)$ so the integral is $\int_{\rho= 0}^1\int_{\theta= 0}^{2\pi}\int_{\phi= 0}^{\pi} e^{-c\rho cos(\theta)sin(\phi)}\rho^2 sin(\phi)d\rho d\theta d\phi$.

The second is $\int_{\rho= 0}^1\int_{\theta= 0}^{2\pi)}\int_{\phi= 0}^{\pi} e^{-c\rho cos(\theta)sin(\phi)}(1- \rho^2)\rho^2 sin(\phi)d\rho d\theta d\phi$

Comment: Is it easy to compute the integrals you wrote above?

Comment: OP was asking for an $n$-dimensional ball, your answer only works for $n=3$